# Spring-boot: How to configure JMS pool number of connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am creating a project with Spring-Boot that uses JMS over ActiveMq.

I set the following properties:

> spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:35000
>
> spring.activemq.pooled=true

It is working fine, but I have no control over the properties of the connection pool. For example, I want to set the max number of connections in the connection pool.

**Is there a way to set that?**

And if I tried to configure ActiveMq myself in my Spring context xml file, Spring-boot is complaining about having problem with Autowiring 2 `ConnectionFactory`!

**Is there a way to tell Spring-Boot not to autoconfigure any ActiveMq connection factory?** (done by `ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration` in the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` library)

Comment: Note that today you can set that in properties: `spring.activemq.pool.max-connections: 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is provide a bean of type `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and instruct Spring Boot to not provide a default one.

The code would look like:

```
@Configuration
class YourActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        return createFactory(); //do whatever you need to here
    }
}
```

In you main Application configuration class add the exclude property to `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class)
//the rest of your annotations
public class AppConfig {

    //declare whatever other beans you need
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to exclude ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration as it's annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class)

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for the comment, but `ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration` is not annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class)` in version 1.1.6.RELEASE. On the other hand, `ActiveMQAutoConfiguration` is. Is this a bug maybe?

Comment: Well that's what I get for only checking the code in master. Yes, that's a bug I think. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1599.

Comment: I was too hasty earlier, and I now stand by my statement that ignoring ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration shouldn't be necessary as it's not an auto-configuration class. Instead, it's imported by ActiveMQAutoConfiguration which, as you've observed _is_ annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class). I've added a couple of tests (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/cf22e28ddc35ee106a2e8b52b4e716609f9f28cb) to verify the behaviour when everything's configured in Java.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Ok, I'll check it out!